# Is there a EJB3 verifier in WildFly like the one provided by JBoss org.jboss.verifier.Main?

Tags: jboss, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.2

I have migrated ejb2.x/Jboss 4.2.3 to EJB3.2/WildFly17. Jboss 4.2.3 has a verifier that can be used in the ant script to validate the ejb app.jar.

Like this

```
<target name="verify">
    <java classname="org.jboss.verifier.Main">
            <classpath refid="verify.path"/>
        <arg value="${lib.dir}/${application.jar}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

I want to verify the application.jar if it is EJB3 complaint. Does WildFly provides any support for this or is it still relavant to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJB3 does not need a verifier like EJ2x. EJB3 expects the bean to be just a valid pojo.